# How to create a list from taxonomy terms?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I tried to render the terms of a Taxonomy in this way:

Category 1

Category 2

Category 3

Category 4

Category 5

Category 6

Category 7

But it is quite difficoult to me.
My steps were:

1. Create a Taxonomy "Sections"
2. Add terms to taxonomy "Sections"
3. Create a query for the terms in taxonomy "Sections"
4. Create a widget in navigation zone with the query assigned

Can any one guide to me to obtain a pure ul and li?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To obtain a pure ul and li

When creating a query in the dashboard, you can choose from multiple options for the Layout. When choosing the 'Raw' layout it gets rendered default as an unordered list.

If you want to gain full control over the rendering you can use the 'Shape' option.

When choosing the Shape option, you can define a 'Shape Type'. Type here what you want (for example SectionList). Next, create a view in your theme's View directory called the same as the Shape Type (SectionList.cshtml) with for example the following content:

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement
@using Orchard.Taxonomies.Models

@{
    var sections = ((IEnumerable<ContentItem>) Model.ContentItems).ToList();
}

<ul>
    @foreach(var section in sections) {
        var termPart = section.As<TermPart>();
        <li><a href="@termPart.Slug">@termPart.Name</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

Take a look at [this post](http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/ways-to-render-lists-of-things) for a good explanation about the rendering of lists.

Comment: I think I miss customize more the query... I only added filter here. Let me try it in some hours to mark as solution

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively make navigation out of taxonomy and avoid query all together. Just go to Admin > Navigation > `Add a new menu` and then just add taxonomy link. Then you can display it with menu widget.